# Texturing a cube in libgdx 3D

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I wrote the following class to create cube models in libgdx.

```
package io.github.l0lk.zombieyeti.block;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.TextureAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.MeshPartBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;

public enum BlockType {

    GRASS("dirt", 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0),
    STONE("stone", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    PLANK("plank", 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0),
    GLASS("glass", 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3);

    public static int TEXTURE_WIDTH = 16;

    String name;
    int textureTopX, textureTopY;
    int textureSideX, textureSideY;
    int textureBottomX, textureBottomY;

    TextureRegion textureRegionTop = null;
    TextureRegion textureRegionSide = null;
    TextureRegion textureRegionBottom = null;

    Model model;

    BlockType(String name, int textureTopX, int textureTopY, int textureSideX, int textureSideY, int textureBottomX, int textureBottomY) {
        this.name = name;
        this.textureTopX = textureTopX;
        this.textureTopY = textureTopY;
        this.textureSideX = textureSideX;
        this.textureSideY = textureSideY;
        this.textureBottomX = textureBottomX;
        this.textureBottomY = textureBottomY;
    }

    public static void createTexturesAndModels(Texture texture) {
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();

        for(BlockType type : values()) {
            type.textureRegionTop = new TextureRegion(texture, type.textureTopX * TEXTURE_WIDTH, type.textureTopY * TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH);
            type.textureRegionSide = new TextureRegion(texture, type.textureSideX * TEXTURE_WIDTH, type.textureSideY * TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH);
            type.textureRegionBottom = new TextureRegion(texture, type.textureBottomX * TEXTURE_WIDTH, type.textureBottomY * TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH);

            int attr = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates;
            modelBuilder.begin();
            MeshPartBuilder meshPartBuilder = modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr, new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.textureRegionTop)));
            meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(type.textureRegionTop);
            meshPartBuilder.rect(-0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f, 0, 0, -1);
            meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(type.textureRegionSide);
            meshPartBuilder.rect(-0.5f,0.5f,0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f,  0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f,0.5f,0.5f, 0,0,1);
            meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(type.textureRegionSide);
            meshPartBuilder.rect(-0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,  0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f, 0,-1,0);
            meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(type.textureRegionSide);
            meshPartBuilder.rect(-0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f, -0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,  0.5f,0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f, 0,1,0);
            meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(type.textureRegionSide);
            meshPartBuilder.rect(-0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f, -0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,  -0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f, -1,0,0);
            meshPartBuilder.setUVRange(type.textureRegionBottom);
            meshPartBuilder.rect(0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f,  0.5f,0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f, 1,0,0);
            type.model = modelBuilder.end();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the texture file I use as input.

[image: Texture file]

That code produces the following cubes (depending on the texture).
[image: Image of the rendered cubes]

Any idea how to fix this? I have tried to read about this but still cant fully understand the problem.

EDIT 1:

After setting every texture to null except in `new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.textureRegionTop)));` I got the following result:

[image: Image of results]

Comment: You have to be more specific: what's the input (texture) and what would you expect to get?

Comment: @Thomas I edited the answer to include the whole enum class and the texture file

Comment: So the problem is that each face looks as if it was using the same texture coordinates (the same texel), right?

Comment: The top, bottom and sides should have different textures (at least on the first cube (grass). Secondly, the texture should not be one color but should be a texture (like that you see on the texture image)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the libgdx api but it might be the material that's being used which is defining the texture (hence the same texture for each cube). The material normally is also used to define lighting information so that might produce the singular color. However, I don't know whether you can pass a null material or not, if no you could try and pass in some identity material (e.g. one which using a white and maybe transparent texture, depending on your texturing settings). Note that materials normally also contain shaders so that could mess with the texture coordinates you supply.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, so I set every texture to null except the first (the createMesh value) and got a texture.

Comment: That indicates that the material is interfering with the texture rendering. I'm not sure how the texture region is applied exactly, i.e. how the uv-coordinates for the vertices are generated. You could try to provide the uv-coordinates manually just to test that. If you provide a texture region the uv-coordinates might also only apply to the texture in that region (which is now null in your case) so there might be some blending etc. involved (blending the material's texture with a null texture should result in the material's texture being used, so that might be why it works now).

Comment: May I ask how you rendered this?

Comment: I am trying to do a similar thing, but not minecraft of course. Can you explain a bit more how you use your class,because it looks really handy. I understand the first bit, but not actually how your render it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us review the classes `Texture` and `TextureRegion` in libGDX:

- **Teture**: A tetxure is a (most commonly 2D) image where the intent is to paste it onto a 3D polygon to give it more visual detail.
- **TextureRegion**: For efficiency and convenience [multiple textures can be combined into a single file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas), as is the case with your image file. So for an image that is not a single texture by itself, you would define parts of the image as separate texture regions.

From a libGDX API perspective, there are two ways to tell it to use a TextureRegion:

1. Call `createDiffuse(TextureRegion)` which sets a fixed region of your image file as texture.
2. Call `createDiffuse(Texture)` to load the whole Texture as Material and then call `setUVRange(TextureRegion)`.

Your error is that you inappropriately mixed those two methods: You call `createDiffuse(TextureRegion)` and then ALSO call `setUVRange(TextureRegion)`, so you define a texture region TWICE. My guess is this results in a tetxure region within a texture region with the size of exactly a single pixel (as there are 16x16 textures of 16x16 pixels) which explains your flat color results.

The easiest way to fix it is using number 2 and **replacing `createDiffuse(type.textureRegionTop)` with `createDiffuse(texture)`!** I will also demonstrate number 1 below for completeness.

---

Before:

[image: img1]

After:

[image: img2]

I also added transparency for glass using `BlendingAttribute(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`:

[image: img3]

And turned back-face culling off using `IntAttribute.createCullFace(GL20.GL_NONE)` and `DepthTestAttribute(false)`:

[image: img4]

The cubes are pointing to the side to due up-direction in OpenGL being the +Y-direction, but I think you'll manage to fix this yourself. (:

---

Here is a complete working example. Create a minimal libGDX project with their tool and save the texture as "minecraft.png" under e.g. `android/assets`. I used Kotlin rather than Java because I had a Kotlin project lying around, but you only need to change your code from two lines before `modelBuilder.begin()` to `.end()` anyway (and glClearColor):

```kotlin
package io.github.l0lk.zombieyeti.block;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.*
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.*
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder

enum class BlockType(var nameca: String, var textureTopX: Int, var textureTopY: Int, var textureSideX: Int, var textureSideY: Int, var textureBottomX: Int, var textureBottomY: Int) {
    GRASS("dirt", 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0),
    STONE("stone", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    PLANK("plank", 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0),
    GLASS("glass", 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3);

    var textureRegionTop: TextureRegion? = null
    var textureRegionSide: TextureRegion? = null
    var textureRegionBottom: TextureRegion? = null
    var model: Model? = null

    companion object {
        var TEXTURE_WIDTH = 16
        fun createTexturesAndModels(texture: Texture?) {
            val modelBuilder = ModelBuilder()
            for (type in values()) {
                type.textureRegionTop = TextureRegion(texture, type.textureTopX * TEXTURE_WIDTH, type.textureTopY * TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH)
                type.textureRegionSide = TextureRegion(texture, type.textureSideX * TEXTURE_WIDTH, type.textureSideY * TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH)
                type.textureRegionBottom = TextureRegion(texture, type.textureBottomX * TEXTURE_WIDTH, type.textureBottomY * TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_WIDTH)
                val attr = (VertexAttributes.Usage.Position or VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal or VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates).toLong()
                val materialAttrs = arrayOf(BlendingAttribute(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), IntAttribute.createCullFace(GL20.GL_NONE), DepthTestAttribute(false))
                modelBuilder.begin()
                modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr, Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.textureRegionTop), *materialAttrs))
                        .rect(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 0f, -1f)
                modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr, Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.textureRegionSide), *materialAttrs))
                        .rect(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
                modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr, Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.textureRegionSide), *materialAttrs))
                        .rect(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f, -1f, 0f)
                modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr, Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.textureRegionSide), *materialAttrs))
                        .rect(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 1f, 0f)
                modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr, Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.textureRegionSide), *materialAttrs))
                        .rect(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1f, 0f, 0f)
                modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr, Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.textureRegionBottom), *materialAttrs))
                        .rect(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1f, 0f, 0f)
                type.model = modelBuilder.end()
            }
        }
    }
}

class Game : ApplicationAdapter() {

    lateinit var environment: Environment
    lateinit var cam: PerspectiveCamera
    lateinit var modelBatch: ModelBatch
    lateinit var models: List<ModelInstance>

    override fun create() {
        environment = Environment().apply { set(ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)) }
        BlockType.createTexturesAndModels( Texture(Gdx.files.internal("minecraft.png")) )
        modelBatch = ModelBatch()
        models = (0..3).map { ModelInstance(BlockType.values()[it].model).apply { transform.translate(it/1f, 0f, 0f) }}

        cam = PerspectiveCamera(67F, Gdx.graphics.width.toFloat(), Gdx.graphics.height.toFloat()).apply {
            position.set(4f, 2f, 2f)
            lookAt(2f, 0f, 0f)
            update()
        }
    }

    override fun render() {
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.width, Gdx.graphics.height)
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        modelBatch.apply {
            begin(cam)
            models.forEach { render(it, environment) }
            end()
        }
    }
}
```